# laravel - how to add prefix in all url without affecting route existing

Tags: php, laravel

i have url like this `mysite.com/company`, i want add prefix to url to become `mysite.com/home/company`.

I've tried to add a route group, but that requires me to update all existing routes.

can i add a prefix in all url without affecting the existing route ?

i used laravel 5.6

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: i used laravel 5.6.39

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a [sandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/n/patient-brook-oa7l-qpjkz) so that you can view and play around with the code used for this answer.

I know the sandbox uses a different Laravel version (version 7), but looking at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing) for version 5.6 the routing does not seem to be that much different than that of version 7.

What you can do is wrap the already existing routes inside an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and assign it to a variable, you can then use this variable and pass it as a parameter to the `group` routing function along with a `prefix`, e.g.

```
$routes = function() {
    Route::get('company', function () {
        return 'companies';
    });

    Route::get('company/{company}', function ($company) {
        return "company $company";
    });

    Route::delete('company/{company}', function ($company) {
        return "deleting company $company...";
    });

    Route::get('company/{company}/staff', function ($company) {
        return "staff list for company $company...";
    });
};

Route::prefix('/')->group($routes);
Route::prefix('/home')->group($routes);
```

When running `php artisan route:list` the following is returned:

```
+--------+----------+------------------------------+------+---------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                          | Name | Action  | Middleware |
+--------+----------+------------------------------+------+---------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user                     |      | Closure | api        |
|        |          |                              |      |         | auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD | company                      |      | Closure | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | company/{company}            |      | Closure | web        |
|        | DELETE   | company/{company}            |      | Closure | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | company/{company}/staff      |      | Closure | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | home/company                 |      | Closure | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | home/company/{company}       |      | Closure | web        |
|        | DELETE   | home/company/{company}       |      | Closure | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | home/company/{company}/staff |      | Closure | web        |
+--------+----------+------------------------------+------+---------+------------+
```

You can see above that the routes can now be accessed via both `/` and `home/`, e.g. `http://example.com/company` and `http://example.com/home/company` without the need for duplicating routes.

If you need to add any more prefixes in the future you just simply add a new `Route::prefix("<prefix>")->group($routes);` to the routes file.

---

The update below is in response to the comment provided by OP.

To get this correct you are looking for a way to automatically convert all instances of the `url` function from `url('someurl')` to `url('home/someurl'`), e.g.

- `url('company')` will become `url('home/company')`
- `url('knowledgebase'`) will become `url('home/knowledgebase')`

If so then I have two solutions for you:

1. Can you not simply do a search and replace within the IDE you are using?
2. You can override Laravel's `url` helper function to prefix all path's with `home/`, to do so you can do the following:

**I have created another [sandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/n/misty-bread-1lol-rohgt) so that you can view and play around with the code used for this answer.**

First create a `helpers.php` file anywhere within your Laravel application, when testing this code I placed the file in the root directory of the application, e.g. `/var/www/html/helpers.php`.

Second you need to override the `url` helper function, to make sure you don't lose any functionality I grabbed the original source code of the function from Laravel's [github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php) repository. I then modified it to include the prefix, so place the following in the new `helpers.php` file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlGenerator;

if (! function_exists('url')) {
    /**
     * Generate a url for the application.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $path
     * @param  mixed  $parameters
     * @param  bool|null  $secure
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlGenerator|string
     */
    function url($path = null, $parameters = [], $secure = null)
    {
        if (is_null($path)) {
            return app(UrlGenerator::class);
        }

        $path = "home/$path";

        return app(UrlGenerator::class)->to($path, $parameters, $secure);
    }
}
```

Next, you need to load your `helpers.php` file before Laravel loads their helper functions, otherwise it wont load, to do so add `require __DIR__.'/../helpers.php';` to `public/index.php` before `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`, e.g.

```
require __DIR__.'/../helpers.php';
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Now you can use the new `url` function within your application, I have given some examples in the `web.php` routes file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    echo url("company");

    echo "<br/>";

    echo url("knowledgebase");
});
```

The above will output to the webpage:

```
http://example.com/home/company
http://example.com/home/knowledgebase
```

Now if you need to change the `url` function slightly to more fit your requirements you can do so by modifying it within the `helpers.php` file.

Comment: but i want call the route just {{url('/company')}}, not {{url('home/knowledgebase')}}, so I don't need to update all existing route name

Comment: @ZaparSiddik I have updated my answer, hopefully it answers your question

Comment: solved !!,  thanks for you're answers. it's very helpful.